# error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor

Tags: android, kotlin

При запуске приложения выводит:

```
error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor.
    private final java.util.List<com.example.network.model.admodel.Catalogue> catalogues = null;
```

Эта ошибка выходит на каждое поле-объект.

```
data class AdWorkerModel(
val age_from: Int?=null,
val age_to: Int?=null,
val candidat: String?=null,
val catalogues: List<Catalogue>?=null,
val client_logo: String?=null,
val education: Education?=null,
val experience: Experience?=null,
val firm_activity: String?=null,
val firm_name: String?=null,
val id: Int?=null,
val payment_from: Int?=null,
val payment_to: Int?=null,
val phone: Any?=null,
val place_of_work: PlaceOfWork?=null,
val profession: String?=null,
val town: Town?=null,
val type_of_work: TypeOfWork?=null,
val work: Any?=null)
```

.

```
@Dao
interface Dao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ChatTable")
    fun getAllChatItems(): Flow<List<AdWorkerModel>>}
```

.

```
@HiltViewModel
class SignInViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repo: MainRepo) : ViewModel() {
    val allItemChat: LiveData<List<AdWorkerModel>> = repo.getAllChatItem().asLiveData()}
```

.

```
  class MainRepo @Inject constructor(private val apiService: ApiService,private  val mainDb: MainDb) {
     val dao = mainDb.getDao()
    fun getAllChatItem() =dao.getAllChatItems()}
```

.

```
 @Entity(tableName = "ChatTable")
data class ChatItemEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "nameUser")
    val name: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "imageUser")
    val image: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "timeUser")
    val time: Int = 0
)
```

Comment: По всей видимости, Room не может понять, каким образом сохранить `List<Catalogue>` в таблицу. Вам нужно написать свой [`TypeConverter`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data). То же самое с объектами. Есть еще вариант использовать анотацию [`@Embedded`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#nested-objects).

Comment: Я поставил  @Embedded, и после этого стала выходить ошибка:Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type). - java.util.List

Comment: В Room нет никакой магии, он не умеет сохранять список в таблицу реляционной базы данных. Вам нужно написать TypeConverter, чтобы объяснить Room, как преобразовать ваш список объектов в один из [поддерживаемых типов базы данных](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).